# Copy files of directory into another using system calls on linux

Tags: c, linux, file, directory, system-calls

Im trying to copy the files from a directory into another using system calls but i get a "violation of segment core" and I don't know why, the first argument is the origin directory, the second the destiny directory, the third is not used and the fourth is the bytes position where I start to copy every file of the first directory with this I mean for example if Pos = 4 and the file is helloo the copied file content would be o because I use lseek to move to pointer to the position 4 and start to copy from there, this is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#define BS 512
#define error(a) {perror(a); exit(1);};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) //argv1 Dir1 argv2 Dir2 argv3 Fich argv4 Pos
{
    DIR *dir1;
    DIR *dir2;
    struct dirent *lectura1;
    struct dirent *lectura2;
    struct stat st;
    int datos1;
    int datos2;
    int size;
    char path[256] = "";
    char path2[256] = "";
    char temp[256];
    char buf[BS];
    int j;
    int i;
    if(argc != 5)
    {
       error("Numero de argumentos incorrecto");
    }
    int Pos = atoi(argv[4]);
    if(Pos < 0)
    {
        error("Pos must be 0 or greater")
    }
    
    if((dir1 = opendir(argv[1])) == NULL){error("Failed to open origin dir");}
    if((dir2 = opendir(argv[2])) == NULL){error("Failed to open destiny dir");}
    
    while((lectura1 = readdir(dir1)) != NULL)
    {
        sprintf(path, "%s/%s", argv[1], lectura1->d_name);
        lectura2 = readdir(dir2);
        sprintf(path2, "%s/%s", argv[2], lectura2->d_name);
        
        if (strcmp(lectura1->d_name, "..") != 0 && strcmp(lectura1->d_name, ".") != 0) 
        {
            if (stat(path, &st) == 0) 
            {
                if (S_ISREG(st.st_mode)) //If is a regular file 
                {
                    if((datos1 = open(path, O_RDONLY, 00600)) == -1){error("Failed to open file");} //Opens the target file of Dir1 to copy inside Dir2
                    size = lseek(datos1,0,SEEK_END);
                    if (size > Pos) //Check if the size of the file is bigger than the position that indicates the point from which to start copying the file
                    {
                        lseek(datos1,Pos,SEEK_SET); //Moves the pointer to the start position of the file1
                        if((datos2 = open(path2, O_CREAT|O_WRONLY, 00200)) == -1){error("Error al abrir archivo copia");}
                        lseek(datos2,0,SEEK_SET);
                        j = BS;
                        i = 0;
                        int n = 0;
                        if ((size - i) < BS) 
                        {
                            j = size - i;
                        }
                        while ((n = read(datos1, buf, BS)) > 0) 
                        {
                            n = write(datos2, buf, j);
                            i = i + n;
                            if ((size - i) < BS) 
                            {
                                j = size - i;
                            }
                        }
                        close(datos1);
                        close(datos2);
                    }    
                }        
            }    
        }           
    }
    close(dir1);
    close(dir2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Without knowing the command line arguments and having a corresponding environment (directories and files) it is difficult to reproduce the problem. Enable compiler warnings and fix them. `argv[4]` is not the right argument for `lseek`. Probably you mean `Pos`. You should be prepared to handle partial `read`s and `write`s. The return value will tell you how many bytes were actually read or written. Run your program in a debugger and check where the problem occurs.

Comment: @Bodo Just debugged with printf, It doesnt print anything Im new to c so do you think that it can be because the name of the file is util1 and Im using a main without a function called util1 or this is a stupid question?

Comment: In my case It crashes because of this line: `lectura2 = readdir(dir2);` You get null in `lectura2` but you don't check it on the next line.
Also I changed the `lseek` line to `lseek(datos1,atoi(argv[4]),SEEK_SET);` because it didn't seem correct to pass a string pointer.

Comment: @GeorgeNechifor Yep my bad, there is a int named Pos wich value is atoi(argv[4]) i corrected it calling pos on the lseek, but why it gets null onlectura2? I mean that argument is supposed to be a directory

Comment: @JamesR I think you should try something like this: 
`lectura2 = readdir(dir2); //remove this line and just use the original filename for the second file
 sprintf(path2, "%s/%s", argv[2], lectura1->d_name);`

Comment: Who on God's good Earth is teaching you to write code such as `if((datos1 = open(path, O_RDONLY, 00600)) == -1){error("Failed to open file");}`?!?!?  Cramming all of that onto one line (plus comments!!) makes your code all but unreadable and therefore extremely bug-prone.  It also makes it literally impossible to step through in a debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, it seems to work like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#define BS 512
#define error(a) {perror(a); exit(1);};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) //argv1 Dir1 argv2 Dir2 argv3 Fich argv4 Pos
{
    DIR *dir1;
    DIR *dir2;
    struct dirent *lectura1;
    struct dirent *lectura2;
    struct stat st;
    int datos1;
    int datos2;
    int size;
    char path[256] = "";
    char path2[256] = "";
    char temp[256];
    char buf[BS];
    int j;
    int i;
    if(argc != 5)
    {
       error("Numero de argumentos incorrecto");
    }
    int Pos = atoi(argv[4]);
    if(Pos < 0)
    {
        error("Pos must be 0 or greater")
    }

    if((dir1 = opendir(argv[1])) == NULL){error("Failed to open origin dir");}
    if((dir2 = opendir(argv[2])) == NULL){error("Failed to open destiny dir");}

    while((lectura1 = readdir(dir1)) != NULL)
    {
        sprintf(path, "%s/%s", argv[1], lectura1->d_name);
        sprintf(path2, "%s/%s", argv[2], lectura1->d_name); //<-- changed param

        if (strcmp(lectura1->d_name, "..") != 0 && strcmp(lectura1->d_name, ".") != 0)
        {
            if (stat(path, &st) == 0)
            {
                if (S_ISREG(st.st_mode)) //If is a regular file
                {
                    if((datos1 = open(path, O_RDONLY, 00600)) == -1){error("Failed to open file");} //Opens the target file of Dir1 to copy inside Dir2
                    size = lseek(datos1,0,SEEK_END);
                    if (size > Pos) //Check if the size of the file is bigger than the position that indicates the point from which to start copying the file
                    {
                        lseek(datos1,Pos,SEEK_SET); //Moves the pointer to the start position of the file1
                        if((datos2 = open(path2, O_CREAT|O_WRONLY, 00200)) == -1){error("Error al abrir archivo copia");}
                        lseek(datos2,0,SEEK_SET);
                        j = BS;
                        i = 0;
                        int n = 0;
                        if ((size - i) < BS)
                        {
                            j = size - i;
                        }
                        while ((n = read(datos1, buf, BS)) > 0)
                        {
                            n = write(datos2, buf, j);
                            i = i + n;
                            if ((size - i) < BS)
                            {
                                j = size - i;
                            }
                        }
                        close(datos1);
                        close(datos2);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    closedir(dir1);
    closedir(dir2); // <-- changed call
    return 0;
}
```